# How to create an Edittext (TextInputLayout) like Android in objective C?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textinputlayout

[image: Image Reference]

See image from the URL for more detail

Comment: What have you tried and why would you want to add Android specific views to iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve TextInputLayout effect with this [library](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/textinputlayout)

here is the [tutorial](https://www.spaceotechnologies.com/create-login-screen-textinputlayout-swift-ios-app/)

for SnakeBar here is [library](https://github.com/stonesam92/SSSnackbar)

hope this help